# ASP.NET Core MVC action method reads an EF Core model from but passes a null value to view and any other method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I retrieve a model from the database, and according to the debugger, when I set a breakpoint, the model is read because I can see the model in the locals window. What could remedy this?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExampleAction(int id)
{ 
    // breakpoint locals window shows details of the record
    ExampleModel assignment = await _context.ExampleModel.FindAsync(id);

    // Here, I get:
    // System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
    ViewBag.assignmentid = assignment.Id
          
    return View(assignment);
}
```

Comment: Just before executing the second line, is `assignment` null or is `ViewBag` null? If neither are null, can you provide the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.   What if you have `var test = assignment` just after the line where you retrieve it from the database?   And then debug / inspect to verify the value of `test` after the assignment?

Comment: @StephenJennings   StackTrace "   at MesureCSharp.Controllers.Admin.DistributorController.<AssignService>d__24.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\Samuel\\Documents\\Mesure\\MesureCSharp\\Controllers\\DistributorController.cs:line 229" string

Comment: @devlincarnate (var test = assignment) + assignment {MesureCSharp.Models.Service_Center.ServiceCenterAssignmentDto} MesureCSharp.Models.Service_Center.ServiceCenterAssignmentDto
  test null MesureCSharp.Models.Service_Center.ServiceCenterAssignmentDto

Comment: (at Viewbag.assignmentid = assignment.Id)   ViewBag.assignmentid null dynamic {object}
+  assignment {MesureCSharp.Models.Service_Center.ServiceCenterAssignmentDto} MesureCSharp.Models.Service_Center.ServiceCenterAssignmentDto
  assignment.Id 2 int
+  test {MesureCSharp.Models.Service_Center.ServiceCenterAssignmentDto} MesureCSharp.Models.Service_Center.ServiceCenterAssignmentDto